# Why did't call web-service if text having spaces in between words.?

Tags: android, web-services, post

My requirement is i want to save some data in database by using web-services. it's working fine up to without spaces between the words.

my problem starts from here if entered text (getting text from EditText) having spaces i am getting this error.

```
Illegal character in path at index 103:
```

these are the strings from edittext : news as, news db.

this is the code

```
try {   
   HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

  HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("mwweb" +channel_token+"/" +data_src_id+
                    "/"+ title+"/"+details);      
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest, localContext);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

  String sResponse = reader.readLine();
  System.out.println(" response" +sResponse);


  } catch (Exception e) {            
    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());    
 }
```

**EDIT:** i got half of the solution from **Android, weakwire** suggetions , if i use this replaceAll(" ", "%20") working if text have only spaces.  if i use encoding working if text have special charecters, did't get for spaces . i want the solution for both(means text having spaces and special charecters).

Comment: does your channel_token or data_src_id or title or details is editText ?

Comment: title and details these are editText values.

Comment: then obviously it will not get called, you marked one thing that whenever there is a space in URL it get converted in to %20. so in your case you need to encode your URL before calling.

Comment: to which format i have to encode .

Comment: see, when you have space in your EditText that means you have something like this in your ( for e.g. )url : http://www.google.com/EditText1 /EditText2 , here we have one space after EditText1, it needs to be replace with %20, just google for Encoding URL , the only logic is, just replace the spaces with %20,

Comment: See the below answer, that's what I am saying.

Comment: @Android Thank you, already i tried from your suggestion i am getting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url is not encoded. Also `URLEncoder.encode` will not help you unless you apply it to each argument seperatly. You can try this

```
String url="myurl" +channel_token+"/" data_src_id+"/"+ title+"/"+details); 
 url=url.replace(" ","%20");
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
```

or

```
channel_token=URLEncoder.encode(channel_token, "UTF-8");
data_src_id=URLEncoder.encode(data_src_id, "UTF-8");
```

... etc for all the arguments

Comment: without using special characters it's(first one) working, if i use special characters in the text what i have to do.

Comment: if i use second one i am getting this response and i am unable to post data . <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> , other than special characters first one is working.

Comment: ? can you paste your code somewhere for the second method? also try with utf-8 (lower case)

Comment: you should use _title _details ... not the original ones.